# WP fallback image in echo statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, var

I am echoing back some HTML for a related posts widget. I want to show the thumbnail image ('get_the_post_thumbnail') if it has one, if not show a fallback. I dont know if I should use the if/else statement in a var (can't get it to work) or what the best method for doing this is.

Here is my echo code:

```
echo '<div class="l-four"><div class="l-twelve l-mb1 recentThumb t-center">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail') .'</div><div class="l-twelve f-size14 f-l-height16 t-center"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" class="c-gold">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a></div></div>';
```

I have tried using the if/else in a var:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] );
} else {
    $img = '<img src="path/to/image" />';
}
```

and echo that out:

```
echo '<div class="l-four"><div class="l-twelve l-mb1 recentThumb t-center">' . $img .'</div><div class="l-twelve f-size14 f-l-height16 t-center"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" class="c-gold">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a></div></div>';
```

but it just defaulted to the else statement, not picking up the thumbnail from articles that have it.

Entire Code block

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] );
    } else {
        $img = '<img src="path/to/image" />';
                }
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3');
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        echo '<div class="l-four"><div class="l-twelve l-mb1 recentThumb t-center">' . $img .'</div><div class="l-twelve f-size14 f-l-height16 t-center"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" class="c-gold">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a></div></div>';               
    }
?>
```

Comment: The if/else statement is fine. The problem seems to be with `has_post_thumbnail()` returning false, but I doubt we can easily figure out why it does. Where are you using this code exactly?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if you evaluate get_the_post_thumbnail() instead of has_post_thumbnail() ?

Comment: Added entire code above

Comment: It sounds to me like your checking `has_post_thumbnail()` and the `$post` global isn't actually referencing your query. Try to pass the ID of the post your working with to it. Also it may be helpful to see the query you're using.

Comment: How would I do that? The entire code is added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you are trying to fetch the thumbnail before you actually have the related posts. For example, you are referencing `$recent["ID"]` when the `$recent` object still doesn't seem to exist. I guess something like this could work for you:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '3');
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]) ) {
        $img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] );
    } else {
        $img = '<img src="path/to/image" />';
    }

    echo '<div class="l-four"><div class="l-twelve l-mb1 recentThumb t-center">' . $img .'</div><div class="l-twelve f-size14 f-l-height16 t-center"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" class="c-gold">' . $recent["post_title"] .'</a></div></div>';               
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So it was a scope issue? moving the if/else inside the  foreach fixed it.

Comment: Not as much a scope issue, but rather about control flow: you wanted to go through every post and check for the image, so you had to loop with the `foreach` and test with the `if` inside.